# How to prove someone has stolen my ether?

Tags: transactions, ether, recovery

About 5 of us at work, got our ether wallets set up by this guy at work, who charged a 10% fee of what we were investing, he had all our information since he set the wallets up for us, since then this guy ended up quitting his job & we all just realized that our ether balances were all zero, he has stolen all our funds, the total investment was $6500, & all 5 of us are left with nothing. Is it possible to find this person through the transactions to prove that he is the one who stole our funds? Is there any way of tracking this guy down?

Comment: Like Thomas said below, if you have the addresses of your accounts, and make them public, then there's more chance someone might have a poke around. The more eyes, the better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blockchain is meant to be a trustless system. By that I mean that you don't NEED to trust anyone to run your business on blockchain.
You introduced trust when you asked your co-worker to create an account for you. At this very moment, you just disabled all the trustless system that Ethereum provided.
You can try whatever you want and aggregate proofs to incriminate him, but you made the first mistake. Many other people have lost ether by mistake in the past. Except for the DAO that concensus decided to revert, no one ever recovered their loss.
This is a hard way to learn but you learned something very useful: trust no bitches ! 
Also you should know that creating your own account is very simple. See myetherwallet site for example.
Anyway, sorry for what you lost.
Don't give up.
Good luck and if you need help, just ask.

Answer (score 3):

I produce a tool called ethslurp (http://ethslurp.com) which allows you to download transactions into and out of any given account as Excel spreadsheets. If you have the account addresses, this may help you track down where the ether currently is. I doubt you'll ever get the money back, but perhaps he made a mistake somewhere.

It's unclear to me how you'd ever prove that he stole the money as opposed to you simply having given it to him and claiming you didn't. It seems to me there is at least a reasonable doubt. Good luck.